# How to replace commas with white spaces in a csv, but inserting a different number of space after each column?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, sed, csv

I have a file in the following format:

```
s1,23,789  
s2,25,689
```

and I would like to transform it into a file in the following format:

```
s1      23  789  
s2      25  689
```

i.e 6 white spaces between the 1st and 2nd column and only 3 white spaces between the 2nd and 3rd column?

Is there a quick way of pulling this off using sed or awk?

Answer (score 6):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IFS=","} {printf("%s      %s   %s\n", $1, $2, $3)}' input_file
```

And equivalently and more terse (from the comments):

```
awk -F ',' '{printf("%s      %s   %s\n", $1, $2, $3)}' input_file
```

Comment: That's assuming that the data fields are of constant width, which I doubt.

Comment: OP was very specific about 6 spaces and 3 spaces....

Comment: OK.  I guess so.  Then you nailed it.

Comment: Cosnider using `-F ','` instead of the BEGIN statement. Makes it shorter

Comment: Also, the `;next` is unnecessary, since there are no blocks or tests after it

Answer (score 5):

#### AWK

Alternative awk with `sprintf()`:

```
$ awk -F ',' '{long=sprintf("%6s"," ");short=sprintf("%3s"," "); print $1long$2short$3 }' input.txt 
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```

And variation on the theme with regular `printf()`:

```
$ awk -F ',' '{printf "%s%6s%s%3s%s\n",$1," ",$2," ",$3}' input.txt                                                      
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```

Yet another variation on the theme of `sprintf()`, but with `sub()` and `gsub()` functions. Since `sub()` edits only first match, it's convenient for us to use it to replace first comma with 6 spaces, and the other one with 3

```
$ awk '{sub(/\,/,sprintf("%6s",""));gsub(/\,/,sprintf("%3s",""));};1' input.txt                                          
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```

---

For the folks who like alternatives, here's other approaches:

#### Perl

```
$ perl -F',' -lane "print @F[0],' 'x6,@F[1],' 'x3,@F[2]"  < input.txt                                                    
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```

#### Python

```
$ python -c 'import sys;lines=[l.strip().split(",") for l in sys.stdin];print "\n".join([ i[0]+" "*6+i[1]+" "*3+i[2] for i in lines])' < input.txt
s1      23   789
s2      25   689
```

#### SED

```
$ sed -e 's/,/      /' -e 's/,/   /'  input.txt                                                                          
s1      23   789  
s2      25   689
```